# Rotation on EditText, apart from using RotationAnimation

Tags: android, rotation, android-edittext

Is there another way of rotating an EditText apart from using the RotateAnimation class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to write your own `EditText` and override the `onDraw`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.save();
   canvas.rotate();
   canvas.restore();
}
```

of course the [TextPaint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html) it is on your own too.